# How to get the "Nyuck, Nyuck, Nyuck" achievement?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

For the "[Nyuck, Nyuck, Nyuck](http://d3db.com/achievement/i/nyuck-nyuck-nyuck)" achievement, you need to kill all three monks in the Drowned Temple "with one blow". So if one of the three goes down first, it fails, and you need to replay the entire Festering Woods part, etc.
After trying it over and over, I ask for your advice.

What's a good way to get this achievement - which difficulty, class, and skills help getting it?

Comment: I would guess any level 60 playing on a normal game would be able to do it with some massive aoe.

Comment: @lyrion that would be my guess too

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Get level 60, skill some AOE skill, like Blizzard for Wizard, Spiked Trap for Demon Hunter etc. Open a game on Normal difficuly. Start the quest. Rally them up. Just let them close in and hit you, then run away. They will all follow you and cluster. Then use your skill and kill them all at once.

10k+ DPS will kill them with one blow.

Answer (score 4):

Demon Hunter Rapid Fire counts as "one blow" (for example can also get mighty blow callouts). Level 36 DH (1k DPS) playing Normal got all 3 drowned temple champions in less than a second, and the achievement.